# Specific AJAX call fails in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a website which does a lot of ajax calls to an API. However now I'm implementing an autocomplete function, and I want to make an AJAX call every time a character is put in the search field. the code with the request is as follows:

```
$('input#search').bind('input', function() { 
    $.getJSON( "http://s14.klup.nl/twitnews/twirus_backend/tweach/api/v1/auto_complete.php?locale=" + locale + "&word_single=" + $(this).val(), function( data ) {
        $('form#searchform ul#autocomplete li').remove();
          $.each(data, function( result, object ){
            $('form#searchform ul#autocomplete').append("<li><a href='/" + locale + "/topic/" + object["word_single"] + "'>" + object["word_single"] + "</a></li>");
          });
        });
    });
```

This works like a charm! Except: IE. So Firefox, Safari, Chrome etc. all no problem, but in IE the request fails and spits out a `No Transport` error. Could this have something to do with the json format? Because to me it seems legit. I can't for the life of me figure out why it fails, more so because the other requests I use on the website DO work in IE. Only this one fails. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

The url is fine, I alerted it before the call, and it is the same as it is in browsers where the call DOES work.

Comment: Have you tested that the strings that are being created for the URL parameters are coming out the same across browsers?

Comment: Yes! I checked the url, by alerting it before the call, and it is exactly the same as it is in other browsers...

Comment: Try this: $.support.cors = true; before sending the request

Comment: Tried it already, didn't work unfortunately :(